# Passing selected radio button value to controller on click of a link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on a project in which we are using ASP.net MVC 3.0 with Razor. 
We have a requirement wherein we have to create a page to display customer list  with radio button to select a row in the list. When user selects a row using radio button and click on Edit/Detail/Delete button respective action will be called in the controller.

I am able to track which radio button is selected but not able to figure out how to pass this value to controller when user clicks on Edit/Detail/Delete button.

Comment: are you using `@Html.RadioButtonFor()` ?? if yes then you will get value on post...

Comment: Hi Yaseer, I am using @Html.RadioButton() not @Html.RadioButtonFor()

Comment: I tried @Html.RadioButtonFor() but id is not being passed while postback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Yaseer and HatSoft,

I have find out way to pass parameter dynamically using ajax.ActionLink, one hidden field and jQuery.
Below is the solution

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { subCategoryId = "0" }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get" }, new { @class = "linkButton", id = "btnEditSubCat" })
<input type="hidden" id="hdnsubCategoryId" />
```

I have added one hidden field which holds currently selected id associated with radio button and assigning it to href using jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function () {
        $('#hdnsubCategoryId').val($(this).val());
        $('#btnEditSubCat').attr('href', "/subcategory/Edit?subCategoryId=" + $('#hdnsubCategoryId').val());
});
})
```

Comment: you should accept your answer, that way it'll no longer show up on the unanswered list. :)